# What is the logic behind picking eigenvectors when eigenvalue is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, intuition

Suppose I had this matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

eigs of $A$ is $-1$, and $0$

What would be the logic in picking the eigenvector for this scenario?

Comment: The system $(A-0I)x=0$ reads simply $x_1=0$, with $x_2$ free, so one eigenvector is $(1,0)^T$.

Comment: It's the same as picking eigenvectors for any other eigenvalue.

Comment: NB that unwinding the definition shows that the $0$-eigenspace of a matrix is precisely its kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about (simple) eigenspaces. The eigenvalue tells you the scaling factor for how that matrix acts on the corresponding eigenspace. (There are some details about generalized eigenvalues that aren't super relevant here) So in the eigenvalue 0 case, the eigenvector tells you what subspace is getting collapsed to the origin.